# Npm Run Dev shows site is working, but npm Run build does not

Tags: npm, next.js

Ok so, I have a nextJS app whose stack versions are `Next.js` v14.1.0, npm -version 10.4.0, node -v
v21.6.2.
But for whatever reason, npm run dev renders everything okay in localhost but once I build the app with `npm run build`, it fails to compile. It shows problems like can't resolve node module "`crypto`", and some webpack issue. I haven't added any webpack package in the project. I All lead to the same problem with the npm run build to try to deploy on cloudflare pages.

Error code looks like:

```
h4wk@H4wK-MacBook-Pro krator-ai-book-generator % npm run build

> krator@0.1.0 build
> next build

   ▲ Next.js 14.1.0
   - Environments: .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js:2:16
Module not found: Can't resolve 'stream'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/create-hash/browser.js
./node_modules/crypto-browserify/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/init.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/index.js
./app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-edge-app-route-loader/index.js?absolutePagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Fauth%2F%5B...nextauth%5D%2Froute.js&page=%2Fapi%2Fauth%2F%5B...nextauth%5D%2Froute&appDirLoader=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&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D!

./node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:3:10
Module not found: Can't resolve 'http'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/oauth/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/client-legacy.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/callback.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/index.js
./app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-edge-app-route-loader/index.js?absolutePagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Fauth%2F%5B...nextauth%5D%2Froute.js&page=%2Fapi%2Fauth%2F%5B...nextauth%5D%2Froute&appDirLoader=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&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D!

./node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:4:11
Module not found: Can't resolve 'https'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/oauth/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/client-legacy.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/callback.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/index.js
./app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-edge-app-route-loader/index.js?absolutePagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Fauth%2F%5B...nextauth%5D%2Froute.js&page=%2Fapi%2Fauth%2F%5B...nextauth%5D%2Froute&appDirLoader=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&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D!

./node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:6:17
Module not found: Can't resolve 'querystring'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/oauth/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/client-legacy.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/callback.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/index.js
./app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-edge-app-route-loader/index.js?absolutePagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Fauth%2F%5B...nextauth%5D%2Froute.js&page=%2Fapi%2Fauth%2F%5B...nextauth%5D%2Froute&appDirLoader=bmV4dC1hcHAtbG9hZGVyP25hbWU9YXBwJTJGYXBpJTJGYXV0aCUyRiU1Qi4uLm5leHRhdXRoJTVEJTJGcm91dGUmcGFnZT0lMkZhcGklMkZhdXRoJTJGJTVCLi4ubmV4dGF1dGglNUQlMkZyb3V0ZSZwYWdlUGF0aD1wcml2YXRlLW5leHQtYXBwLWRpciUyRmFwaSUyRmF1dGglMkYlNUIuLi5uZXh0YXV0aCU1RCUyRnJvdXRlLmpzJmFwcERpcj0lMkZVc2VycyUyRmhhcXVlaWZ0ZWtoYXJ1bCUyRkRvY3VtZW50cyUyRkZpdmVyciUyRlByZXN0b256ZW4lMkZrcmF0b3IlMkZrcmF0b3ItYWktYm9vay1nZW5lcmF0b3IlMkZhcHAmYXBwUGF0aHM9JTJGYXBpJTJGYXV0aCUyRiU1Qi4uLm5leHRhdXRoJTVEJTJGcm91dGUmcGFnZUV4dGVuc2lvbnM9dHN4JnBhZ2VFeHRlbnNpb25zPXRzJnBhZ2VFeHRlbnNpb25zPWpzeCZwYWdlRXh0ZW5zaW9ucz1qcyZiYXNlUGF0aD0mYXNzZXRQcmVmaXg9Jm5leHRDb25maWdPdXRwdXQ9JnByZWZlcnJlZFJlZ2lvbj0mbWlkZGxld2FyZUNvbmZpZz1lMzAlM0Qh&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D!

./node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:1:17
Module not found: Can't resolve 'querystring'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/oauth/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/client-legacy.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/callback.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js
./node_modules/next-auth/index.js
./app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-edge-app-route-loader/index.js?absolutePagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Fauth%2F%5B...nextauth%5D%2Froute.js&page=%2Fapi%2Fauth%2F%5B...nextauth%5D%2Froute&appDirLoader=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&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D!


> Build failed because of webpack errors
h4wk@H4wK-MacBook-Pro krator-ai-book-generator %
```

**Tried re-installing node modules, but no luck**

**take note that this wasn't happening prior to December, 2024.**

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Since, npm run dev works fine on localhost, I tried npm run build. But it fails everytime both on localhost and on cloudflare build log.
Tried to resolve issues based on error messages. Tried adding and resolving "crypto" module issues surfing through internet. Tried adding webpack to build the next app but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Take a look at these threads perhaps. Looks like a webpack issue, you may need to change your config

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/25276#issuecomment-844600644

https://github.com/mswjs/msw/issues/1142

Comment: Didn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Has content of your `npm run build` in `package.json` contain config file? And run on window?